# Merging/Concat/Joining two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge, concatenation

i have a pandas dataframe with a distinct code identifier as detailed below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1], ['b', 2],['c', 3],['d', 4],['e', 5],['f', 5]],
                   columns=['code', 'value1'])
```

with a second dataframe with the following

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['a', 11], ['b', 12],['c', 13],['d', 14],['e', 15],['f', 16],['g', 17], ['h', 2],['i', 3],['j', 4],['k', 5],['l', 5]],
                   columns=['code', 'value2'])
```

i would like to only see the codes identified in df1 (i.e a-f) and have a third column entitled value2.

I have tried

df1 = df1.join(df2, on = 'Code')

but i keep getting a value of NaN

I have looked at several places and seen merge, concat and join, but none of them appear to work

Comment: What's your desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on = 'code')
```

since you named the column 'code' not 'Code'

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='code')
    code    value1  value2
0   a   1   11
1   b   2   12
2   c   3   13
3   d   4   14
4   e   5   15
5   f   5   16
```

Or do you mean by with `how='outer'` and `merge`?

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on='code')
   code  value1  value2
0     a     1.0      11
1     b     2.0      12
2     c     3.0      13
3     d     4.0      14
4     e     5.0      15
5     f     5.0      16
6     g     NaN      17
7     h     NaN       2
8     i     NaN       3
9     j     NaN       4
10    k     NaN       5
11    l     NaN       5
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

To only see the codes identified in df1 (i.e a-f) and have a third column entitled value2, you should use `merge` method with `how='inner'` and `on='code`:

```
>>> df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='code')
    code    value1  value2
0   a   1   11
1   b   2   12
2   c   3   13
3   d   4   14
4   e   5   15
5   f   5   16
```